# Angular request via proxy not reaching rust api

Tags: angular, rust

I have an Angular 16 project where I need to make a call to an external API. I have set up a proxy with the following config:

```json
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:5000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that it is indeed working. On startup `ng serve --verbose --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.json` spits out this:
`[HPM] Proxy created: /api  -> http://localhost:5000`.

On the other side I have an API written in Rust using actix_web (the latest version):

```rust
use actix_cors::Cors;
use actix_web::{
    get, middleware, post, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder, ResponseError,
};
use std::env;

#[get("/api")]
async fn standard_get() -> impl Responder {
    "Hello from API".to_owned() + "\n"
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "actix_web=debug,actix_server=debug");
    env_logger::init();

    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
            .wrap(Cors::permissive())
            .service(standard_get)
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 5000))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

As you can see, the rust API is listening on port `5000`. It's using no encryption and I enabled CORS through `actix_cors`. Using `curl` I confirmed that the API by itself is working correctly.

When trying to access the API through the proxy with `http://localhost:4200/api`, the debug log suggests that the request is routed correctly:

`[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] GET /api -> http://localhost:5000`

However I always get a 403 Forbidden and I cannot figure out why.

The debug log on the rust server says nothing, therefore implying that the request doesn't even reach the API.

I am absolutely lost. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would man-in-the-middle the server with `socat`: ```socat -v tcp-listen:5050,forever,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:5000```.  Then point your frontend to `5050`.  This will let you see all TCP/HTTP traffic to your server.  This will divide the domains in half and tell you if the problem is your API or your frontend.

Comment: @RossRogers As soon as I redirect my frontend to 5050 and use socat with the exact command you provided, it works! Without socat it doesn't. I have absolutely not the slightest idea what is causing this.

Comment: @Chris, that is very strange.     If you nuke `socat` and then change this line `.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5000))?`  to bind to 5050, does the issue reappear ? `

Comment: @RossRogers yes, it does.

Comment: Very curious.   Maybe try binding to `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`?  I think you know the issue is now within the rust code itself.  You said, "Using curl I confirmed that the API by itself is working correctly."  Did you copy the _exact_ curl from the chrome debugger networking tab and use _that_ curl to confirm it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I did that too. No matter what I do, something prevents access through the internal proxy of angular but not direct access. I am using a MacBook and I somehow suspect that some firewall or apple specific guideline whatever is blocking the traffic because it's always 403, not 404 or 50x. Will investigate further. That theory supports socat working, because socat bypasses the IP Stack.